# Show that the smallest eigenvalue is strictly positive.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices, matrix-analysis

I have a $2\times 2$ real, symmetric and positive definite matrix $B_{x,n}$ which depends on a point $x\in[0,1]$ and $n\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that for sufficiently large $n$, the smallest eigenvalue of $B_{x,n}$ is strictly positive uniformly on $x$.

To do so, I managed to show that $B_{x,n}\to B$ as $n\to\infty$ with $B$ positive definite (and so, has only strict positive eigenvalues).

It is known that the smallest eigenvalue equals the solution $\inf_{\lVert z \rVert=1}z'B_{x,n}z$. Then for each nonzero $z\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $z'B_{x,n}z\to z'Bz>0$. However, I believe that the desired result can be shown only if $z'B_{x,n}z\to z'Bz>0$ uniformly on $\{z:\lVert z\rVert=1\}$. Is it right?

Can you give me suggestions?

This is Lemma 1.5 of Tsybakov's [Introduction to nonparametric estimation](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=mwB8rUBsbqoC&pg=PP8&lpg=PP8&dq=tsybakov+smallest+eigenvalue+nonparametric&source=bl&ots=Z7uJUaNqzC&sig=ACfU3U271ns0lWatLvXSNW2q-YL51W4u3Q&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOud-P4-3lAhXOJrkGHVQcCJ0Q6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=tsybakov%20smallest%20eigenvalue%20nonparametric&f=false), by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B$ is positive definite then $\det(B)>0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(B)>0$.

Since the determinant and the trace are continuous functions and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}B_{x,n}=B$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\det(B_{x,n})=\det(B)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\operatorname{tr}(B_{x,n})=\operatorname{tr}(B)$.

So there is $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $\det(B_{x,n})>\frac{1}{2}\det(B)>0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(B_{x,n})>\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(B)>0$.

Therefore the product and the sum of the two eigenvaues of $B_{x,n}$ are positive for $n>N$. So the eigenvalues are positive for $n>N$.

Comment: Thanks for showing this different solution for pointwise convergence. Can you show that this N holds uniformly for any x in [0,1]?

Comment: @CelineHarumi Hi Celine. Is the convergence of $B_{x,n}$ to $B$ uniform? Does $B$ depend on $x$?

Comment: Hi. Your pointwise result solved my problem. In the question, I assumed pointwise convergence, but I think I can show that the convergence is uniform. $B$ does not depend on $x$.